# How can I flatten nested arrays in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have complicated array with nested arrays.
For example if I want to get data from last array then I have to write:
`partners[0].products[0].campaigns[0].nameCampaign` or `.type` or `.price` etc.

[image]

I'd like to flatten this array. And this is what I expect:
[image]

Is it possible at all?

---

@EDIT 
This is part of `console.log(JSON.stringify(partners, 0, 4));`:

```
[{
    "_id": "57727902d0a069e41a34eece",
    "namePartner": "Self",
    "products": [{
        "_id": "57727910d0a069e41a34eed0",
        "nameProduct": "Singl",
        "campaigns": [{
            "_id": "57727937d0a069e41a34eed1",
            "type": "lead",
            "nameCampaign": "Camp 0"
        }]
    }, {
        "_id": "5774cb68c594b22815643b37",
        "nameProduct": "DrugiPartner"
        "campaigns": [{
            "_id": "5774cb78c594b22815643b38",
            "type": "subscription",
            "nameCampaign": "DrugaKampania"
        }, {
            "_id": "5774cbedc594b22815643b3a",
            "type": "subscription",
            "nameCampaign": "TrzeciaKampania"
        }, {
            "_id": "5774cbf9c594b22815643b3b",
            "type": "subscription",
            "nameCampaign": "CzwartaKampania"
        }]
    }, {
        "_id": "5774cbdbc594b22815643b39",
        "nameProduct": "Trzeci"
        "campaigns": []
    }]
}]
```

Comment: can you the actual object structure by `console.log(JSON.stringify(partners, 0, 4));` ? show the output

Comment: Ok I edited post already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In plain Javascript you could use an array with the references to the wanted items and the arrays and use an iterative recursive approach to get the wanted array.

Edit

For more than one property to add, you could use an array for more than one item.

One property:

```
{ use: 'namePartner' }
```

Multiple properties:

```
{ use: ['nameCampains', 'type'] }
```

```js
function iter(a, r, l) {
    if (Array.isArray(a)) {
        a.forEach(function (b) {
            var use = level[l].use,
                rr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(r));
            (Array.isArray(use) && use || [use]).forEach(function (c) {
                rr[c] = b[c];
            });
            iter(b[level[l].array], rr, l + 1);
        });
        return;
    }
    result.push(r);
}

var partners = [{ namePartner: 'Tesco', products: [{ nameProduct: 'New', campains: [{ nameCampains: 'Apple', type: 'appleType' }, { nameCampains: 'Lenovo', type: 'lenovoType' }] }] }, { namePartner: 'Eko', products: [{ nameProduct: 'Fresh', campains: [{ nameCampains: 'Asus', type: 'asusType' }, { nameCampains: 'Dell', type: 'dellType' }] }, { nameProduct: 'new', campains: [{ nameCampains: 'Samsung', type: 'samsungType' }] }] }],
    level = [{ use: 'namePartner', array: 'products' }, { use: 'nameProduct', array: 'campains' }, { use: ['nameCampains', 'type'] }],
    result = [];

iter(partners, {}, 0);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I wondering what should I change if I want to add `type` from campaings array?

Comment: Last thing I forgot. I prefer this format: 
`[
  [
    namePartner: "Tesco",
    nameProduct: "New",
    nameCampaign: "Apple",
    type: "appleType"
  ]...]` as a result

Answer (score -1):

You could use [get](https://lodash.com/docs#get) from [lodash](https://lodash.com/):

```
var CAMPAIGN_NAME_PATH = ['partners', 0, 'products', 0, 'campaigns', 0, 'nameCampaig'];
var campaignName = _.get(JSONObject, CAMPAIGN_NAME_PATH, 'optionalDefaultCampaignName');
```

Or you could try playing with [flatten](https://lodash.com/docs#flatten), [flattenDeep](https://lodash.com/docs#flattenDeep) and [flattenDepth](https://lodash.com/docs#flattenDepth) and rearrange the JSON object structure first before accessing it (note that these three methods only work on arrays, not key-value objects).